# How does a website detect installed chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have read so many similar questions but none of them really got the answer I need. So I am building a website that has to do with crypto and most of the sites I visited seem to have a way of checking if the extension is installed.

No, they don't own the extension. They are checking for various crypto wallet extensions and I just can't seem to figure out how.

This is how it looks on a https://app.edgeprotocol.io/pool site: [when I disable an extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMN7K.png) and [when I enable an extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zao2o.png).
I pretty much want to do the same thing.

I tried tracking it through dev tools and I think I tracked it to a single script but i may be way off.

```
<script>
    ! function(e) {
        function r(r) {
            for (var n, c, f = r[0], u = r[1], i = r[2], d = 0, p = []; d < f.length; d++) c = f[d], Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o, c) && o[c] && p.push(o[c][0]), o[c] = 0;
            for (n in u) Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(u, n) && (e[n] = u[n]);
            for (l && l(r); p.length;) p.shift()();
            return a.push.apply(a, i || []), t()
        }

        function t() {
            for (var e, r = 0; r < a.length; r++) {
                for (var t = a[r], n = !0, f = 1; f < t.length; f++) {
                    var u = t[f];
                    0 !== o[u] && (n = !1)
                }
                n && (a.splice(r--, 1), e = c(c.s = t[0]))
            }
            return e
        }
        var n = {},
            o = {
                10: 0
            },
            a = [];

        function c(r) {
            if (n[r]) return n[r].exports;
            var t = n[r] = {
                i: r,
                l: !1,
                exports: {}
            };
            t.l = !0, t.exports
        }
        c.e = function(e) {
            var r = [],
                t = o[e];
            if (0 !== t)
                if (t) r.push(t[2]);
                else if(e!=32){ 
                    var n = new Promise((function(r, n) {
                        t = o[e] = [r, n]
                    }));
                    r.push(t[2] = n);
                    var a, f = document.createElement("script");
                    f.charset = "utf-8", f.timeout = 120, c.nc && f.setAttribute("nonce", c.nc), f.src = function(e) {
                        return c.p + "static/js/" + ({}[e] || e) + "." + {
                            0: "e7f018ae",
                            1: "eee60155",
                            2: "172ffe18",
                            3: "5655d2db",
                            4: "331f241f",
                            5: "5c1b6fdd",
                            6: "6b4e7793",
                            7: "09e74c9f",
                            8: "78e5cdcd",
                            12: "0d08120d",
                            13: "23a22926",
                            14: "369f18c9",
                            15: "90551739",
                            16: "0c091b4d",
                            17: "4fe15447",
                            18: "945e6f1c",
                            19: "15213fdb",
                            20: "411469d7",
                            21: "f4f7eec1",
                            22: "10b0441c",
                            23: "98d16a1b",
                            24: "483791c0",
                            25: "a1bf00a1",
                            26: "623c0f3c",
                            27: "0426dbac",
                            28: "a6fe3b57",
                            29: "53a75f07",
                            30: "3206fc2e",
                            31: "e2d785cf",
                            32: "78f1f23f",
                            33: "9a43406a",
                            34: "60e677e7",
                            35: "4e1bb26f",
                            36: "9f8a6a9b",
                            37: "004d2c34",
                            38: "2b386dfe",
                            39: "53c58b77",
                            40: "78884ecc",
                            41: "4e64c95a",
                            42: "927c26a2",
                            43: "a76aa392",
                            44: "b21a0b09",
                            45: "45464245",
                            46: "c2c3e6e7"
                        }[e] + ".chunk.js"
                    }(e);
                    var u = new Error;
                    a = function(r) {
                        f.onerror = f.onload = null, clearTimeout(i);
                        var t = o[e];
                        if (0 !== t) {
                            if (t) {
                                var n = r && ("load" === r.type ? "missing" : r.type),
                                    a = r && r.target && r.target.src;
                                u.message = "Loading chunk " + e + " failed.\n(" + n + ": " + a + ")", u.name = "ChunkLoadError", u.type = n, u.request = a, t[1](u)
                            }
                            o[e] = void 0
                        }
                    };
                    var i = setTimeout((function() {
                        a({
                            type: "timeout",
                            target: f
                        })
                    }), 12e4);
                    f.onerror = f.onload = a, document.head.appendChild(f)
                }
            return Promise.all(r)
        }, c.m = e, c.c = n, c.d = function(e, r, t) {
            c.o(e, r) || Object.defineProperty(e, r, {
                enumerable: !0,
                get: t
            })
        }, c.r = function(e) {
            "undefined" != typeof Symbol && Symbol.toStringTag && Object.defineProperty(e, Symbol.toStringTag, {
                value: "Module"
            }), Object.defineProperty(e, "__esModule", {
                value: !0
            })
        }, c.t = function(e, r) {
            if (1 & r && (e = c(e)), 8 & r) return e;
            if (4 & r && "object" == typeof e && e && e.__esModule) return e;
            var t = Object.create(null);
            if (c.r(t), Object.defineProperty(t, "default", {
                    enumerable: !0,
                    value: e
                }), 2 & r && "string" != typeof e)
                for (var n in e) c.d(t, n, function(r) {
                    return e[r]
                }.bind(null, n));
            return t
        }, c.n = function(e) {
            var r = e && e.__esModule ? function() {
                return e.default
            } : function() {
                return e
            };
            return c.d(r, "a", r), r
        }, c.o = function(e, r) {
            return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e, r)
        }, c.p = "/", c.oe = function(e) {
            throw console.error(e), e
        };
        var f = this["webpackJsonpedge-web-app-v2"] = this["webpackJsonpedge-web-app-v2"] || [],
            u = f.push.bind(f);
        f.push = r, f = f.slice();
        for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++) r(f[i]);
        var l = u;
        t()
    }([])
</script>
```

I downloaded the page and did a liveserver through VSC and tried debuging through the script but it is way too big for me plus i don't really understand a lot of it but i noticed a difference when the extension was on and off.

Comment: That code is obfuscated, it's very difficult to tell what it's doing.

Comment: Those crypto extensions probably add some global variable to `window`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).